# Symfony 2, overwriting bundle view (TWIG) SonataAdmin

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-sonata

I'm wondering how to extends views in twig across bundle.

I'm using **SonataAdmin bundle**, which provides it's own twig views for list rendering:

- CRUD/base_template.html.twig
- CRUD/base_list.html.twig (extends above twig)

  - ...

It also has a config "templates/layout" which seem to be a "wrapper" for any views (not actually sure to understand how that works)

My application has it's own layout and thus needs the SonataAdmin to somehow extends this layout.

*How am I suppose to do that?*

I wanted to modifiy the config "templates/layout" twig file making it extends my layout and putting it's content into a block.
But this  throws an memroy exhausted issue.

I'm new with Symfony2, this seem to be a basic concept but can't figure out how to do this properly.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can put the new twig file en /app/Resources/views